# TypeScript Class with built-in fuction

Tags: javascript, class, typescript

For some reason, when I try to create a simple class in TypeScript I'm getting errors in the toJSON() function "*duplicate identifier 'this'* ". What's the correct way of referencing the properties in a sub?

If I remove the '*this.*' and just try to Stringify {lat, lng} I get the error "*cannot find 'lat', did you mean 'this.lat'* ".

Any suggestions?

```
class LatLng {
    lat?: number;
    lng?: number;

    constructor(lat: number, lng: number) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    toJSon() {
        return JSON.stringify({ this.lat, this.lng });
    };
}
```

Comment: Pass a valid object to JSON.stringify something like `{lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sami.

18 years writing JavaScript and I failed to spot the obvious, doh!

the correct code should have been:

```
class LatLng {
    lat: number;
    lng: number;

    constructor(lat: number, lng: number) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    toJSon() {
        return JSON.stringify({ lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng });
    };
}
```